# How do I update the utc timestamp on the server database

Tags: php, forms, datetime, time

I am working on a doctoral survey that has to keep track of the time a participant works through a process on a web screen.  Time only is all that is necessary.  I have set up the database to keep track of the set of predefined users, the start time (as datetime type), and ending time (as datetime type).  When a participant opens the screen a modal form is presented that requires clicking on a button that will activate a form submission.  This form submission is supposed to update the start time in the users row on the server database.  The following is the code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['time']) {
$time= UTC_TIMESTAMP();
$sql = "UPDATE `response` SET `screen1_start`=($time) WHERE `id`= 100102";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
Time</label> <input type="time" name="time" >
<br>
<input type=submit value="Click Here to Begin">
</form>
```

It doesn't work.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"... does it show any errors; does it insert an invalid value in the database, or none at all; does it kick the cat? do you even have a database connection? do you normally use MySQL functions instead of PHP functions?

Comment: You have to add more details, as @MarkBaker says, for instance, WHY it doesn't work.

Comment: `"UPDATE response SET screen1_start=UTC_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id= 100102";`

Comment: Sorry, Mark.  coding frustration set in.   By "doesn't work" I mean that when I open the form on the website and click on the "Click Here to Begin" button no entry is made in the database to update that record. The webpage has an action as if it is reloading, which I expect, but there is no entry made in the field in the database.  Hope that answers your response.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function UTC_TIMESTAMP() in /home/dlc32164/public_html/iconsurvey.info/testemr2.php on line 70. This is the error I get.  what i believe I need is a default utc time stamp that is automatically entered in the time input on the form.  NOt quite sure this is the solution.  But it is what I am working with. thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are calling a SQL function from PHP.
You have two options:

1. Replace your `UTC_TIMESTAMP` for a php function that does the same thing, namely `gmdate` (https://www.php.net/gmdate) (assuming UTC and GMT are the same thing). In your code:

   `$time = gmdate();`
2. Use `UTC_TIMESTAMP` in your SQL call, not in PHP (and this is probably what you wanted to do). In your code:

   `$time= "UTC_TIMESTAMP()";`

Also, be aware of the difference in the moment each sentence is executed. First one runs when PHP call is resolved, second one runs when SQL query is executed.